# JQuery Line Chart's X Axis not display in ASP.NET, C#, SQL Server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, chart.js

I have a SQL Server database table and I want to that record display in jQuery line chart. I tried more time to display my data in chart. but that asp page is loaded successfully and no chart viewed.

My aspx markup is as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <asp:Literal ID="ltChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
</form>
```

My `aspx.cs` code behind is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        ShowData();
}

private void ShowData()
{
    String myConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FFASDBConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnection);

    String query = "SELECT TOP 10 [temperature],[dateTime] FROM [FFAS].[dbo].[ForestFireDataset] ORDER BY [dateTime] DESC";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    DataTable tb = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        tb.Load(dr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);

        con.Close();
    }
    catch { }

    if (tb != null)
    {
        String chart = "";
        chart = "<canvas id=\"line-chart\" width=\"100%\" height=\"40\"></canvas>";
        chart += "<script>";
        chart += "new Chart(document.getElementById(\"line-chart\"), { type: 'line', data: {labels: [";

        string valueX = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < tb.Rows.Count; i++)
            valueX += tb.Rows[i]["dateTime"].ToString() + ",";

        chart += valueX;

        chart += "],datasets: [{ data: [";

        // get data from database and add to chart
        String value = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < tb.Rows.Count; i++)
            value += tb.Rows[i]["temperature"].ToString() + ",";

        value = value.Substring(0, value.Length - 1);
        chart += value;

        chart += "],label: \"Air Temperature\",borderColor: \"#3e95cd\",fill: true}"; // Chart color
        chart += "]},options: { title: { display: true,text: 'Air Temperature (oC)'} }"; // Chart title
        chart += "});";
        chart += "</script>";

        ltChart.Text = chart;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ltChart.Text` only updates the text, not the html. Change your markup from

```
<div>
  <asp:Literal ID="ltChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id='ltChart' runat='server'></div>
```

Then, instead of `ltChart.Text`, you would use `ltChart.InnerHtml` (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml?view=netframework-4.8)).

ASP.NET webforms is obsolete, so if it's a new application, it would be best to use MVC or Blazor.